# How to get textbox value in node.js file?

Tags: html, node.js, textbox, http-post

This is my html code:

```
<form id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
    <textarea name="txtFolderName" rows="1"></textarea>
    <button type="create" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                <span>Create Folder</span>
            </button>
</div>
```

When I click the "Create Folder" button, I will do some function based on the textbox value. How to get the textbox value to the node.js file during POST method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For express you can use bodyParser() middleware (https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) and get submited fields from req.body.

```
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());

app.post('/uploaded',function(req, res, next){
    var txt_folder_name = req.body.txtFolderName;
    //...
});
```

Comment: anything i need to change in html file to call the POST method while clicking the Create Folder button?

Comment: when i click the Create Folder button, the POST method is not calling.

Comment: 1) use type="submit" for button tag. 2) you can add action="/uploaded" atribute to form tag to specify you action route